# Spring Boot 2.2 Multi Module Project auto configuration JPA failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have a Spring-Boot multimodule Project.
Main Module is a Vaadin Web-App (at the Moment very simple) and a second Module called Login with Spring Entitys, Repository and Service bean.

In the Login Module I have written Testcode that runs against a H2 Database. Tests are green, Entity was created, repository exists and so on. (Everything fine)

When I try to start the WebApp I allways get the Message

> A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

My Main Applicattion Class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "eu.dwich.btc", exclude = ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@Import(BtcBackendLoginConfig.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then my Config Class in the module

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = BtcBackendLoginConfig.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = BtcBackendLoginConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = BtcBackendLoginConfig.class)
public class BtcBackendLoginConfig {
}
```

and the properties file

```
database.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
database.database-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/btc_dev
database.database-user=btc_dev
database.database-user-password=xxxxx
# --------------------------------------
# special DB settings
database.hibernater-format-s-q-l=true
database.hibernater-gen-statistics=true
database.hibernate-dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
# possible: create-drop, none, validate, update, create
database.hibernate-ddl-auto=create-drop
database.create-db-script=true
```

First (maybe simple) Question, where should I put the application.properties to configure the database, in the web Project or in the Login module?

Second Question what I'm doing wrong? is it not possible to get the spring boot autoconfiguration to work? (I don't whant to configure datasource and entitymanager)

I have tryed a lot of different configrurations nothing worked until now.

Thanks in advance

Update 1:
there is only one line with a warning, no other stacktrace

```
2020-09-24 08:07:34.788  INFO 19699 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/h2-console/**'], []
2020-09-24 08:07:34.802  INFO 19699 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@b246c96, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@f632a44, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3bd390ec, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@44e09d5a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@30d21b64, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1eed7157, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1d1c15ef, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@15a14e1e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6a47a0c5, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5492fd4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4f5c34f5]
2020-09-24 08:07:34.825  WARN 19699 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userGroupRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#542c45c7' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#542c45c7': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2020-09-24 08:07:34.827  INFO 19699 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

At the end ther is only this message, is it possible to get more information?

```
2020-09-24 08:07:34.887 ERROR 19699 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Update:
This output will be generated when turning debug on:

```
Exclusions:
-----------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:680) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1451) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at eu.dwich.btc.Application.main(Application.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
```

why does spring exclude the whole spring Data stack??

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is a collection of annotations https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html which already contains  ```@SpringBootConfiguration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @ComponentScan```. You don't need to repeat them again in `BtcBackendLoginConfig`

Comment: You can place your properties file under `src/main/resources` to be found under classpath. You can externalise these properties as well if you dont want to keep it in your codebase, refer this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config. Once you fix these suggestions (in my 2 comments), your datasource should be built with autoconfiguration

Comment: I have removed the annotations and added the @SpringBootApplication. My application.properties is placed under src/ain/resources but I sill get the error **A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.**

Comment: Could you please provide the exception stack trace?

Comment: added updates to Main Question

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation and look at some tutos. To configure datasource, your properties should start with `spring.datasource.`

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong variable keys so Spring cannot configure the objects required.

Instead, use the following

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/btc_dev
spring.datasource.username=btc_dev
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto=create-drop
```

Also, make sure you have all the required libraries on the classpath.
You need at least javax.persistence-api and hibernate.

I would also advice you NOT to use `basePackageClasses` unless you know what it does. If you place your Application configuration in his own package instead of the root, Spring won't be able to find any eligible classes.
At least for now, use `basePackages = "eu.dwich.btc"` instead.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) is a list of common Spring properties.
Next to the # DATASOURCE section you see the reference to `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: so I have changed the properties in the application.properties file. changed the basePackageClasses to basePackages. I have **<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>** on the classpath so jarkarta.persistence and hibernate is on the classpath, nothing changed, autoconfig of springDataJpa in Module is not aktive... when I run tests all whent well... strange

Comment: Is it possible for you to share what you have on any public git service?

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom file , you must be missing some dependencies. I was also same problem and resolved after carefully gone through pom file , posgress driver jar was missing and spring-data depenndency was missing. Its giving very generic error you should enable stack trace
"server.error.include-stacktrace=never"
to get more detailed error.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the error

1. Spring applikation simple without imports

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "eu.dwich.btc", exclude = ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

2. the backend config needs some modifikation

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = "eu.dwich.btc")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "eu.dwich.btc")
@Import({
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@Profile("!test")
public class BtcBackendLoginConfig {
}
```

the second @SpringBootApplication was an error and is not needet
without the Autoconfig imports it won't work

and be carefull with the properties, tada.....

```
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop is wrong
#spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop is also wrong
# the right one (as mentioned by Nico Van Belle) is: 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

and if your run an real database (not H2) the default ddl-auto= is none

In my opinion the import of the autoconfig classes is not the best way, but it works.

Comment: please add it to the question itself, adding the exception stack trace as an answer will mislead others as it is difficult to make out that it is additional info about question itself